# How to read a line from a text file in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c

After exhaustive googling and visiting many forums, I am yet to find a good comprehensive answer for this question. A lot of the forums suggest using the get line 
`istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n )` function. My question is what if I don't know what the length of each line is and cannot predict what the size may be? Also what is it's equivalent in C?

Is there any specific function in c /c++ to read one single line each time from a text file ?

Explanation , with Code snippets will help me a lot.

Comment: This isn't a dup as it specifically asks about C, and the supposed 'dup' is specifically asking about C++.

Comment: @sje This question says C++ in it too...

Comment: @DannyBeckett Yes I noticed. I don't think that's relevant to my point, as this one (unlike the other) asks about C, which makes it qualitatively different.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In c, you could use fopen, and getch. Usually, if you can't be exactly sure of the length of the longest line, you could allocate a large buffer (e.g. 8kb) and almost be guaranteed of getting all lines.

If there's a chance you may have really really long lines and you have to process line by line, you could malloc a resonable buffer, and use realloc to double it's size each time you get close to filling it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void handle_line(char *line) {
  printf("%s", line);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size = 1024, pos;
    int c;
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(size);

    FILE *f = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    if(f) {
      do { // read all lines in file
        pos = 0;
        do{ // read one line
          c = fgetc(f);
          if(c != EOF) buffer[pos++] = (char)c;
          if(pos >= size - 1) { // increase buffer length - leave room for 0
            size *=2;
            buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, size);
          }
        }while(c != EOF && c != '\n');
        buffer[pos] = 0;
        // line is now in buffer
        handle_line(buffer);
      } while(c != EOF); 
      fclose(f);           
    }
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: char c; ???!!!
close(f) ?? and malloc.h!!! not stdlib.h

Answer (score 29):

In C++, you can use the global function std::getline, it takes a string and a stream and an optional delimiter and reads 1 line until the delimiter specified is reached. An example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("filename.txt");
    std::string line;

    while( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
        std::cout<<line<<'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program reads each line from a file and echos it to the console.

For C you're probably looking at using `fgets`, it has been a while since I used C, meaning I'm a bit rusty, but I believe you can use this to emulate the functionality of the above C++ program like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line[1024];
    FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt","r");

    //Checks if file is empty
    if( fp == NULL ) {                       
        return 1;
    }

    while( fgets(line,1024,fp) ) {
        printf("%s\n",line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With the limitation that the line can not be longer than the maximum length of the buffer that you're reading in to.

Comment: Thanks. How would we do the same in C? any tht's ?

Comment: Updated my post with how I recall doing it, I hope it is correct as I put it, otherwise I'll correct the post once people point out what I did wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was a better way than using a buffer of fixed length. I guess I now know that we need to hard code the buffer size .

Comment: I guess you could store the start position of a 'line' (Beginning of file or after new line), then scan through the file until you reach either the end of the line or the end of the file. Then take this position, find the difference in bytes from the first position, allocate a buffer large to hold this number of bytes, set the fp using fseek to the start of the line and read the data in to the buffer? I hope that made some sense.

Comment: You could search for the end of line char '\n' and then allocate a buffer.

Comment: Please close of also the file pointer `fclose (fp);`

Answer (score 8):

In C, fgets(), and you need to know the maximum size to prevent truncation.

Answer (score 7):

im not really that good at C , but i believe this code should get you complete single line till the end...

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()   
{      
  char line[1024];    
  FILE *f=fopen("filename.txt","r");    
  fscanf(*f,"%[^\n]",line);    
  printf("%s",line);    
 }
```

Comment: You should avoid `fscanf` because it causes buffer overflows. It provides now way to limit the size of the input to the size of the buffer that's writing to (here, `line`).

Answer (score 6):

`getline()` is what you're looking for. You use strings in C++, and you don't need to know the size ahead of time.

Assuming std namespace:

```
 ifstream file1("myfile.txt");
 string stuff;

 while (getline(file1, stuff, '\n')) {
      cout << stuff << endl;
 }

 file1.close();
```

Comment: Note: You want `std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&)` not `std::istream::getline`.

Comment: How would we do it in C?

Comment: @EternalLearner, I've got some example code (and a screencast) posted here: https://spectrum42.com/introduction-to-c-reading-a-line-of-text/