# Copy file content to a string

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, ifstream

I want to copy contents in a text file to a `string` or a `*char`. It would be better if I can copy the  file content to an `array` of strings (each line an element of that `array`). This is my code:

```
int main() {
   ifstream inFile;
   inFile.open("index.in.txt"); //index.in has in each line a name and at the end there is a "."
   char ab[11];
   int q=0;
   char *a[111];
   if (inFile.is_open()) {
      while (!inFile.eof()) {
         inFile >> ab; //i think i don't understand this line correctly
         a[q]=ab;
         cout<<a[q]<<endl;
         q++;
      }
   }
   else{ 
     cout<<"couldnt read file";
   }
   inFile.close();
   cout<<"\n"<<ab<<endl; //it shoud be "." and it is
   cout<<"\n"<<a[0]<<endl; //it should be "ion" but it gives me "."
   return 0;
}
```

All values in the a `array` are equal to the last line which is dot

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035674/how-to-read-line-by-line-or-a-whole-text-file-at-once)

Comment: You should be using `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an array of character pointers. Also, do you want each line in its own string, or each word?

Comment: each line has only one word so it makes no difference for me

Comment: @MohitJain thanks i'll check that

Comment: Don't do `while (!inFile.eof())`, it will not work as you expect and will cause you to iterate once to many. Instead do `while (inFile >> ab)`. The reason is that the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond end of the file.

Comment: +1 for proper formatting, and you have tried some debug prints and your suspection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to slurp a file into a std::string in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your only buffer everytime in `inFile >> ab;`
You read a line in buffer and save the address of buffer somewhere. Next time you read next line in the same buffer and save the exact same address as second line. If you read back your first line you will end up reading updated buffer i.e. last line.

You can change your code to

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
   ifstream inFile;
   inFile.open("index.in.txt"); //index.in has in each line a name and at the end there is a "."
   string ab; //char ab[11];
   int q=0;
   vector< string > a(111); //char *a[111];
   if (inFile.is_open()) {
      while (!inFile.eof()) {
         inFile >> ab;
         a[q]=ab;
         cout<<a[q]<<endl;
         q++;
      }
    }
    else cout<<"couldnt read file";
    inFile.close();
    cout<<"\n"<<ab<<endl; //it shoud be "." and it is
    cout<<"\n"<<a[0]<<endl; //it should be "ion" but it gives me "."
    return 0;
}
```

Better use std::string and std::vector instead of arrays.

Comment: std::string and std::vectors are smart containers that take care of memory management. So each time you assign a string to vector[idx], a new buffer would be created for vector[idx]. For more details you can read about [c-dynamic memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) malloc etc, C++ dynamic memory i.e. new/delete and then basic STL (std::string, std::vector, std::list, std::set, std::map etc.

Comment: Note: [`while (!inFile.eof())` is a *bad idea*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @WhozCraig i copied the code from a site, then made it for and array of chars instead of *char

Comment: @MohitJain so i suppose if want to do it with arrays and *chars then i have to manually take care of the memory allocation, hmm...

Comment: You need to use malloc/new and free/delete in your code to take care of memory allocation. Or char *a[111]; needs to be replaced with a[111][11] and you need to read directly into a.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main() {
   ifstream inFile;
   inFile.open("index.in.txt"); //index.in has in each line a name and at the end there is a "."
   std::vector< std::string > lines;
   std::string line;
   if (inFile.is_open()) {
      while ( getline( inFile, line ) ) {
         lines.push_back( line );
      }
   }
...
```

now `lines` is a vector of string, each is a line from file

Comment: thanks, it is more complicated for me, but hey, i should learn :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

bool ReadFile(const std::string &sFileName, 
              std::vector<std::string> &vLines)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(sFileName);
    if (!ifs)
        return false;
    std::string sLine;
    while (std::getline(ifs, sLine))
        vLines.push_back(sLine);
    return !ifs.bad();
}

int main() 
{
    const std::string sFileName("Test.dat");
    std::vector<std::string> vData;
    if (ReadFile(sFileName, vData))
        for (std::string &s : vData)
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to read a line you MUST use `std::getline`. The `>>` operator will only read a **word**, that is a sequence of characters ended by a whitespace.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline