# Sequential Access Files Problems in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, readfile, sequential

The program should read in a C++ program from a cpp file, and prints all non-keyword identifiers into a text file.

> First in load function, I am trying to code 3 different ways to read
>   the cpp file. But the number of lines always count 201 lines. The real
>   answer is 103 lines.
>
> Second in deleteCharacterConstants function, why
>   it doesn't work when i use?
>
> ```
> && line[b] != '\'' or '''
> ```
>
> Third, i have no ideas to code getIdentifiers, legal, isNumber,
>   isKeywords, and isDuplicate
>   function.Can anyone help me?? If you can ,tell me the logic and
>   sample.
>
> Last,thanks a lot.

There is my full program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace::std;

// read in a C++ program from a cpp file, and put it to the array "program".
void load(char program[][200], int &numLines);

void deleteComments(char line[]); // if there is a single-line comment in "line", delete it.

void deleteStringConstants(char line[]); // if there are string constants in "line", delete them.

void deleteCharacterConstants(char line[]); // if there are character constants in "line", delete them.

// put all identifiers in "line" into identifiers[ numIdentifiers ].
void getIdentifiers(char line[], char identifiers[][32], int &numIdentifiers);

// if character is a letter, digit or underscore, then return true, otherwise return false.
bool legal(char character);

// print all non-number, non-keyword strings in "identifiers" into a text file.
void store(char identifiers[][32], int numIdentifiers);

bool isNumber(char string[]); // if "string" consists of digits only, then return true, otherwise return false.

bool isKeywords(char string[]); // if "string" is a keyword of C++, then return true, otherwise return false.

// if there is a nonnegtive integer i < pos such that identifiers[ pos ] is equal to identifiers[i],
// then return true; otherwise return false.
bool isDuplicate(char identifiers[][32], int pos);

const char keywords[][20] = { "auto", "break", "case", "char", "const", "continue", "default",
"define", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extern", "float", "for",
"goto", "if", "int", "long", "register", "return", "short",
"signed", "sizeof", "static", "struct", "switch", "typedef",
"union", "unsigned", "void", "volatile", "while", "bool",
"catch", "class", "const_cast", "delete", "dynamic_cast",
"explicit", "false", "friend", "inline", "mutable", "namespace",
"new", "operator", "private", "protected", "public",
"reinterpret_cast", "static_cast", "template", "this", "throw",
"true", "try", "typeid", "typename", "using", "virtual", "include" };

int main()
{
    char program[1000][200];
    int numLines = 0;

    load(program, numLines); // reads in a C++ program from a cpp file, and put it to the array program.

    char identifiers[2000][32];
    int numIdentifiers = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        deleteComments(program[i]); // if there is a single-line comment in program[ i ], delete it.
        deleteStringConstants(program[i]); // if there are string constants in program[ i ], delete them.
        deleteCharacterConstants(program[i]); // if there are character constants in program[ i ], delete them.
        if (strcmp(program[i], "") != 0)
            // put all identifiers in program[ i ] into identifiers[ numIdentifiers ].
            getIdentifiers(program[i], identifiers, numIdentifiers);
    }

    // print all non-number, non-keyword strings in "identifiers" into a text file.
    store(identifiers, numIdentifiers);

    system("pause");
}
    void load(char program[][200], int &numLines){
    ifstream inFile("test.cpp", ios::in);

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; !inFile.eof(); i++){
        inFile.getline(program[i], 200);
        numLines++;
    }
    inFile.close();
}

void deleteComments(char line[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while (line[i] != '\0' && (line[i] != '/' || line[i + 1] != '/'))
        i++;

    if (line[i] == '/' && line[i + 1] == '/')
    {
        line[i] = '\0';
        return;
    }
}


void deleteStringConstants(char line[])
{
    int b = 0;
    int e;
    while (line[b] != '\0')
    {
        while (line[b] != '\0' && line[b] != '\'')
            b++;
        if (line[b] == '\0')
            break;
        e = b + 1;
        if (line[e] == '\0')
            break;
        while (line[e] != '\0' && (line[e - 1] == '\\' || line[e] != '\''))
            e++;
        if (line[e] == '\0')
            break;
        for (int i = b; i <= e; i++)
            line[i] = ' ';
        b = e + 1;
    }
}


void deleteCharacterConstants(char line[])
{
    int b = 0;
    int e;
    while (line[b] != '\0')
    {
        while (line[b] != '\0' && line[b] != '"')
            b++;
        if (line[b] == '\0')
            break;
        e = b + 1;
        if (line[e] == '\0')
            break;
        while (line[e] != '\0' && (line[e - 1] == '\\' || line[e] != '"'))
            e++;
        if (line[e] == '\0')
            break;
        for (int i = b; i <= e; i++)
            line[i] = ' ';
        b = e + 1;
    }
}

void getIdentifiers(char line[], char identifiers[][32], int &numIdentifiers){

}

bool legal(char character){
    return 0;
}

void store(char identifiers[][32], int numIdentifiers)
{
    ofstream Result("Words.txt", ios::out);


    for (int i = 0; i < numIdentifiers; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 32; j++){
            Result << identifiers[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    Result.close();
}

bool isNumber(char string[]){
    return 0;
}

bool isKeywords(char string[]){
    return 0;
}
bool isDuplicate(char identifiers[][32], int pos){
    return 0;
}
```

the input cpp file:

```
// Fig. 6.20: fig06_20.cpp
// Demonstrating C++ Standard Library class template vector.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void outputVector( const vector< int > & ); // display the vector
void inputVector( vector< int > &, int start ); // input values into the vector

int main()
{
   vector< int > integers1( 7 ); // 7-element vector< int >
   vector< int > integers2( 10 ); // 10-element vector< int >

   // print integers1 size and contents
   cout << "Size of vector integers1 is " << integers1.size()
      << "\nvector after initialization:" << endl;
   outputVector( integers1 );

   // print integers2 size and contents
   cout << "\nSize of vector integers2 is " << integers2.size()
      << "\nvector after initialization:" << endl;
   outputVector( integers2 );

   // input and print integers1 and integers2
   cout << "\nEnter 17 integers:" << endl;
   inputVector( integers1, 1 );
   inputVector( integers2, integers1.size() + 1 );

   cout << "\nAfter input, the vectors contain:\n"
      << "integers1:" << endl;
   outputVector( integers1 );
   cout << "integers2:" << endl;
   outputVector( integers2 );
   ......
```

the contents in the output file should appear as follows:

> ```
> iostream
> iomanip
> vector
> std
> outputVector
> inputVector
> start
> main
> ......
> ```

Comment: Too many questions here. Please reduce your scope.

Comment: Off topic: `!eof()` as a loop condition is almost always wrong and is wrong here. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Off topic: consider using std::set<std::string> instead of a 2D array of char for `keywords`

Comment: off topic: not using `std::string`s is really making this harder on you.

Comment: Off topic: Calling `exit` in a C++ program is a really bad idea. It ends the program right then and there. Stacks don't unroll, destructors don't get called, and resources don't cleaned up. It's a bad scene.

Comment: Recommendation: Comment out the rest of the code for now and concentrate on getting the load function reading the correct number of lines from the file. The file parsing is useless if the file input is wrong. Garbage in == garbage out. This is a good basis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035674/how-to-read-line-by-line-or-a-whole-text-file-at-once . once you are reading the file correctly, function by function add the rest of the parsing. If you add too much at a time and have a bug, there are more places to hide the bug. If you add one thing at a time and know all the old stuff works...

Comment: As an added bonus, if you have one question and one buggy function, people are a lot more likely to help.

Comment: @user4581301 I solve the first question. It should be the new function.