# Read input file until certain line c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming, so I was wondering...

If I have an input file consisting of 100 lines, how do I read only up to line 50 and print out each line?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a variable to keep track of many lines you've read and stop when it is equal to 50.

Comment: If you've tried and have a specific issue post an example of the issue and the code

Comment: 1. Take and initialize a counter to zero (to count the number of lines you read) 
2. Use a loop and continue it until the counter value is 50
3. Inside loop read a line from file and increment the counter by 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read line by line or a whole text file at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035674/how-to-read-line-by-line-or-a-whole-text-file-at-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a fstream object fstream f("filename");
2. Keep a counter, read lines from file till the counter less than 50
   Something like this

   ```
     counter = 0;
     while((counter < 50) && (f.good())
     {
        getline(f,str);
        cout<<str<<endl;
        counter++
     }
   ```

   Note: this is not the full code, but guideline how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'fstream' to read your file and count each 'readline'. Each 'readline' means a full line which terminated with '\n'(return value without it). That should be useful.