# How to load a string made of 2+ words into a string array

Tags: c++, string

For my basics of programming project number 2, i have to construct a small app that teaches the user english words and expressions. Apart from the source code, my project also needs two .txt files attached. Both of the txt files contain 100 words, in polish and english respectively. I know how to input words from the file into a string array, however i have trouble with expressions. For example; "To kill two birds with one stone" has to be just one element of the array i'll be using in the program. Each of the words/expressions in txt file is contained within one line like this:

> Dog 
> Cat 
>  Woman 
>  By the skin off their teeth 
>  Lion

Is there a function in fstream library that conveniently allows me to accomplish my task?

Comment: `std::string line; std::getline(myfile, line);` will read a line of text into a `std::string`.

Comment: @drescherjm So far my code looks like this `fstream plik("PolskieSlowka.txt", ios::in);
 
 string slowko;
 while(plik >> slowko){
 odpowiedzi[i] = slowko;
 i++;
 }` , How can i implement getline in there?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> lines; while (std::getline(plik, slowko)) lines.push_back(slowko);`

Comment: Replace `while(plik >> slowko)` with `while(getline(plik,sloko))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read line by line or a whole text file at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035674/how-to-read-line-by-line-or-a-whole-text-file-at-once)