# Implementing cat in Linux system

Tags: c++

This code was for implementing cat in Lin, and when I compiled it, it returned me "tp undefined". When I asked my professor, he said the way I used getline is in C language. I'm confused.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
  FILE* file;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    file = fopen(argv[i],"w");//

    if (file < 0) {
      perror("Error, Can't open file!");
      return -1;
    }

    if (file.is_open()) {
      string tp;
      while (getline(file, tp)) {  // c type
        printf("%d\n", tp);
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `printf()` instead of just `std::cout`? Also, `file.is_open()` shouldn't work when `file` is of type `FILE*`... Why aren't you using `std::ifstream`? There's a lot wrong here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read line by line or a whole text file at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035674/how-to-read-line-by-line-or-a-whole-text-file-at-once)

Comment: You may have mis-interpreted the instruct. except for `getline`  the rest of the code is C, not C++. `file.is_open()` would sort-of be C++, but `FILE*` has no `is_open` method to call.

Comment: Ok; are you *supposed* to be doing this in C, or are you supposed to be doing it in C++? I know you've tagged it C++ but this is quite the mix of C and C++, so I just want to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

1. `printf` is incorrectly formatted. `%d` is for signed integers. `%s` is for strings of characters (More info [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)). Additionally, if you want to work with `printf()` you will need a C string or to call the `std::string::c_str()` function.
2. You're doing things in C style (using `FILE*`, `fopen()`, etc).

**Solution:**

1. If you still want or need to use a C style, replace with `printf("%d\n", tp);` with `printf("%s\n", tp.c_str());`.
2. Use a C++ style instead:

- `FILE*` -> `std::ifstream`.
- `fopen()` -> `std::ifstream::is_open()`.
- `file < 0` -> `std::ifstream::fail()`.
- `perr` -> `std::cerr`.
- `printf()` -> `std::cout`.
- `fclose()` -> `std::ifstream::close()`.

**Additional information:**

1. `using namespace std;` is considered a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        std::ifstream file(argv[i]);
        if(file.fail())
        {
            std::cerr << "Error opening file.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        std::string tp;
        while(std::getline(file,tp))
            std::cout << tp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am downvoting. Even though this is correct, it is not gonna help OP.

Comment: Why it is not gonna help OP?

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting right here! I just realize that I mix the c++ & c type together, bc professor said we should use fopen() fclose() write() those calls and I have no idea wt those call in the c++.

Comment: `fopen() -> std::ifstream::isOpen()` is wrong if I'm not mistaken. Should be `std::ifstream::open()` instead.

Comment: Also, `file.is_open()` is C++. From comments on the OP, that doesn't seem to be in C. The OP would need a C equivalent for that as well.

Comment: A more general comment is that while I agree with most of this, you might just want to double-check your C/C++ style differences. The OP has definitely mixed them together very well, and while you generally have separated the C++ from the C, there are a few you have missed. You might want to just do a double check and make sure you haven't missed anything.

Comment: Hi, I want to ask, is that fgets, strstr, fputs,fclose,fopen all belongs to C language? Where I can find the equivalent for those?

Comment: Yes, they belong to C.. Their equivalents are `std::getline()`, `std::string::find()`, `std::ofstream::operator<<()`, `std::fstream::close()` and `fstream::open()` in that order. You should probably read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn how to use them.

Comment: I think so, I have no idea why my college mainly recommends C++ but our prof asked us mainly use C.....

Comment: how about about fwrite & fread? what's the equivalent for that one.

Comment: Their equivalents are `std::ofstream::write` and `std::ifstream::read`, but I recommend you to use `std::ofstream::operator<<()` and `std::getline()` instead.